# JSON parsing string but not xmlhttprequest responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

[SOLVED]
I have a terrible headache, because I am new to JS and AJAX/JSON and cannot seem to figure out why this is happening.  I am getting a JSON formatted response that looks like this when output on my client web page:
  `[{"ticket_id":"2","ticket_name":"super_rugby_18_Aug_2017","ticket_desc":"Brumbies vs Sharks, 14:30","ticket_price":"420.00"}]`

The problem is, that I cannot parse the responseText with JSON.  But whenever I hardcode the parsed string to be `[{"ticket_id":"2","ticket_name":"super_rugby_18_Aug_2017","ticket_desc":"Brumbies vs Sharks, 14:30","ticket_price":"420.00"}]`, the problem goes away.

But of course, I need the database request to be parsed and not the hardcoded string.  Please help.  Here is my code that is not working:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var input = String(this.responseText);      
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(input);
        document.getElementById("history").innerHTML = jsonObj[0].ticket_id;
    }
}
```

Hardcoded 'string' variable that can be parsed:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {   
        var string = '[{"ticket_id":"2","ticket_name":"super_rugby_18_Aug_2017","ticket_desc":"Brumbies vs Sharks, 14:30","ticket_price":"420.00"}]';   
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(string);
        document.getElementById("history").innerHTML = jsonObj[0].ticket_id;
    }
}
```

Here is the output of stringify: 
  `"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n[{\"ticket_id\":\"1\",\"ticket_name\":\"IIC_match3\",\"ticket_desc\":\"\",\"ticket_price\":\"589.99\"},{\"ticket_id\":\"2\",\"ticket_name\":\"super_rugby_18_Aug_2017\",\"ticket_desc\":\"Brumbies vs Sharks, 14:30\",\"ticket_price\":\"420.00\"}]\r\n\r\n"` The array is filled in this php loop:

php loop I use to send the JSON array

```
$rows = array();
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $r;   
}
$json = json_encode($rows);
echo $json;
```

SOLUTION:
Guess what the problem was? My web service is running in a Linux VM environment, and my calling web client was too. Now when I tried doing the httprequest from a WINDOWS machine to the VM, the JSON.parse works! What could be wrong with my Linux configuration?

Comment: please can you again check like are you getting response as an array or or an object, That is the only possibility which can create problem

Comment: I would double check on the response you are getting , console it out and see if it is in the format you expect it, 

Also make sure the this object is the xhr object you had created

Comment: @amitwadhwani what is the difference between getting it as an array or as an object?

Comment: If you are not getting an array then we might not use jsonObj[0] but jsonObj.ticket_id

Comment: @amitwadhwani The problem is, the line with the parse code stops everything after it from working.  It causes the script to stop.  So doesn't matter whether I use it as array or as object

Comment: If you know the point where there is issue then kindly put try catch and check the exception and please let us know the exception. Also kindly use JSON.stringify instead of String() and please check

Comment: @amitwadhwani Thanks, this might be causing the issue.  I put more info the the post for you to look at.

Comment: Yes so response isn't in proper format, kindly mark my answer as helpful if it has helped.

Comment: Add it as an answer and I'd gladly select it.  But please give more info if you can figure out why it is outputting newlines and end of line characters

Comment: The newlines are not a problem. JSON allows for such white space.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Note that a script does not just stop. It can exit with an exception, but then you see the error in the console. You can put `console.log` after the assignment to `innerHTML` to see it gets there. What is the value of `input`?

Comment: @trincot the error I get in console is SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.  Input is "undefined"

Comment: Try with adding `trim()`: `JSON.parse(string.trim());`.

Comment: I tried various ways with trim() and it still did not work.

Comment: Guess what the problem was? My web service is running in a Linux VM environment, and my calling web client was too.  Now when I tried doing the httprequest from a WINDOWS machine to the VM, the JSON.parse works!  What could be wrong with my Linux configuration?

Comment: `jsonObj.[0]` is a syntax error. That's why your first code doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Bergi I must have misstyped it here.  But that wasn't causing the issue.